# ExtJS 4 - Extra border after adding a bottom toolbar

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, extjs4, border

I have an ExtJS4 app with a moderately complex layout consisting of a couple of nested panels, each with layouts of type `border`.  I can't figure out how to get rid of a 'double border' that exists when I add a bottom toolbar to one of the panels.

See the jsFiddle here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/5fwLz/2/

I'm just trying to figure out how to make the border above 'button' look right.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT-  Solution I used: http://jsfiddle.net/5fwLz/4/

This is a bit cleaner I think than Akatum's solution below and the borders also maintain a clean look when the south region is made collapsible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is quite a hack, but it works. You can set `border` attribute of south border region to `false` and then by using `style` attribute define its right, left and top border:

```
{
    region: 'south',              
    border: false,
    style: {
      borderRight: '1px solid #99BCE8',
      borderLeft: '1px solid #99BCE8',
      borderTop: '1px solid #99BCE8'
    },
    split: true,
    height: '25%'                
}
```

Edited fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5fwLz/3/

Comment: Thanks! I didn't use this exactly, but it did lead me to figuring out the solution I ultimately went with.  See my solution in the original post

Answer (score 2):

For those who might stumble across here. I found a slightly nicer method using the **bodyBorder** config.

```
region: 'center',
border: false,
bodyBorder: false,
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5fwLz/15/